# Django: Select multiple field values and add them in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a django-project where i have to create exam paper and add questions to them..

I need help in creating a view in which for a particular exam i first select the subject and chapter and after submitting it i get all the questions related to them as checkboxes to select multiple values and enter marks for each question.

I have created a dependent dropdown list using [SimpleIsBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) but that lets me add only question at a time which is i don't like..

Please anyone give the solution or hint on how i could implement this. Thanks in advance.

**models.py**

```
from questions.models import Question, Subject, Chapter

class SubjectiveName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    for_class = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=(
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(12),
    )
)

    PART = (
        ("A", "A"),
        ("B", "B"),
        ("C", "C"),
        ("D", "D"),
        ("E", "E"),
)

    part = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PART, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    max_marks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def marks_added(self):
        sum = 0
        for question in self.subjective.all():
            sum += question.marks
        return sum

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return urls.reverse("subjective:detail", args=(str(self.pk)))

    def get_chapters(self):
        chapters = {}
        for question in self.subjective.all():
            chapter = question.questions.chapter
            chapters[chapter] = chapters.get(chapter, 0) + 1
        return chapters

class SubjectiveQuestions(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(SubjectiveName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="subjective")
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True)
    marks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, 
        help_text="If adding a question- leave blank to assign the default 
        marks")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questions.question

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return urls.reverse("subjective:detail", args=(str(self.exam_id)))
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import SubjectiveQuestionForm
from questions.models import Chapter, Question

class SubjectiveQuestionsCreateView(gn.edit.CreateView):
    model = md.SubjectiveQuestions
    form_class = SubjectiveQuestionForm
    template_name = "subjective/new_question.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.exam_id = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        if not form.instance.marks:
            form.instance.marks = form.instance.questions.marks
        return super(SubjectiveQuestionsCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

to handle the ajax request.

```
def load_questions(request):
    subject_id = request.GET.get("subject")
    chapter_id = request.GET.get("chapter")

    if subject_id and not chapter_id:
        questions = Question.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id)
        return render(request, "subjective/questions_dropdown_list.html", {
        "questions": questions
    })
    elif chapter_id:
        questions = Question.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id, chapter_id=chapter_id)
        return render(request, "subjective/questions_dropdown_list.html", {"questions": questions}


def load_chapters(request):
    subject_id = request.GET.get("subject")
    question_id = request.GET.get("question")
    if not question_id:
        chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id)
        return render(request, "subjective/chapters_dropdown_list.html", {"chapters": chapters})
    elif question_id:
        chapter = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id).chapter
        chapters = Chapter.objects.exclude(name=chapter).filter(subject_id=subject_id)
        return render(request, "subjective/chapters_dropdown_list.html", {"chapter": chapter, "chapters": chapters})
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import SubjectiveQuestions
from questions.models import Chapter, Question

class SubjectiveQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectiveQuestions
        fields = "subject", "chapter", "questions", "marks"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["chapter"].queryset = Chapter.objects.none()
        self.fields["questions"].queryset = Question.objects.none()

        if "subject" in self.data:
            try:
                subject_id = int(self.data.get("subject"))
                chapter_id = int(self.data.get("chapter"))
                self.fields["chapter"].queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id)
                self.fields["questions"].queryset = Question.objects.filter(subject_id=subject_id, chapter_id=chapter_id)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
```

Comment: Can you add code to show what you have tried so far to achieve what you want? And where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: added the code.. for the chained dropdown list i just followed the Simple is better complex tutorial...

Comment: Take a look at https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html this should help simplifying your code. and you only need to add the field name to the list of `forwards`.

Comment: @jackotonye Thank you very much.. i will definitely try it..